# SQL Server multiply multiple columns by values in a column in a second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large data set which has following columns:

```
[ID] [code_1] [code_2] [code_3] [code_4] 
         [days_code_1] [days_code_2] [days_code_3] [days_code_4]
```

The `ID` column is not unique, the `[code_n]` columns are text and the `[days_code_n]` columns are numeric.

In a second table I have two columns, one with code values which match `[code_n]`, and `[cost value]` which corresponds to each code.

I want to be able to multiply the `[days_code_n]` by the `[cost value]`. I can do this individually, but for reasons out of my control I have 50 `[code_n]`  and `[days_code_n]` columns. As the ID value is not unique I have to keep the data in the current format.

Can anyone advise me how to multiply the values in the  code_days column, by the value in [the cost_value] variable in the second table without running 50 queries.

Comment: Please mention your DBMS

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post, I am using SSMS 2014 - and I am fairly new to using it!

Comment: SSMS is not a DBMS - it's a SQL query tool. But as it can only work with SQL Server, it's safe to assume you are using SQL Server.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Are you expecting each row returned to have additional columns for `[T1].[days_code_n] * [T2].[cost value]`?  Are you looking for a sum of all of the values in each row? The sum across all rows?  A sum grouped by `[code_n]`?

Comment: Yes, I would like new columns for the output cost* days, I will sum up to grand total, but need the intermediate totals.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention the names of your tables I call them `Table1` and `Table2`.

You can join in the second table for every `code_n` column you have:

```
SELECT Table1.ID
      ,Table1.days_code_1  * t2_01.cost_value AS result1
      ,Table1.days_code_2  * t2_02.cost_value AS result2
      ,Table1.days_code_3  * t2_03.cost_value AS result3
      ...
      ,Table1.days_code_50 * t2_50.cost_value AS result50
  FROM Table1
       JOIN Table2 t2_01 ON Table1.[code_1]  = t2_01.[code_n]
       JOIN Table2 t2_02 ON Table1.[code_2]  = t2_02.[code_n]
       JOIN Table2 t2_03 ON Table1.[code_3]  = t2_03.[code_n]
       ...
       JOIN Table2 t2_50 ON Table1.[code_50] = t2_50.[code_n]
```

And make sure that you have a foreign key on every `Table1.code_...` column which references `Table2.code_n`. Otherwise the query could be very slow.

Comment: Thank you, table 2, t2, has just two columns with , code_n and cost_value, with column code_n containing all the codes  in rows - so not sure the above would work.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understood it as well. I changed the example to have column Table2.code_n